# Caret not visible with TMP_InputField created from script

Tags: unity, c#, input, text-mesh-pro

I'm modding an Unity game. I don't have access to its source, to any Unity editor or assets. All I have is BepInEx and some C# scripting, plus whatever Visual Studio can decompile from dlls.

I create an `TMP_InputField` when the user presses Enter as follows:

```cs
var canvas = new GameObject("CommandConsoleCanvas");
var c = canvas.AddComponent<Canvas>();
c.renderMode = RenderMode.ScreenSpaceOverlay;

var inputField = new GameObject("CommandConsoleInput");
inputField.transform.parent = canvas.transform;

var inputFieldText = inputField.AddComponent<TMP_InputField>();
var txt = inputField.AddComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
inputFieldText.textComponent = txt;

inputFieldText.fontAsset = fontAsset;
inputFieldText.pointSize = 20;
inputFieldText.text = "example...";
inputFieldText.enabled = true;
inputFieldText.caretColor = Color.white;
inputFieldText.caretWidth = 4;
inputFieldText.selectionColor = Color.white;
inputFieldText.onFocusSelectAll = false;

var rect = inputField.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
rect.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(400, 25);

inputFieldText.Select();
inputFieldText.ActivateInputField();
```

This sort of works. I can see the text and type in. However, there  is no caret and no indication of the current selection.

**How can I make the caret and current selection render?**

There must be some settings or components I'm missing but can't figure it out via Googling and looking at the API.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer burried several pages deep in google search pointing to the [unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/creating-a-complete-tmp-input-field-via-script.625735/#post-4191340).

Basically, one has to re-enable the component because the canvas is created via `OnEnable` that is probably executing too early before the other components have been setup. (Also the highlight starts working too but of course white on white is not good.)

```cs
inputFieldText.selectionColor = Color.gray;

inputFieldText.enabled = false;
inputFieldText.enabled = true;
```

Now it works for me as expected.